# Trouble with path specifications when running RStudio from a console

Tags: r, windows, cmd, path, rstudio

I have R script within a plain text file named "TestFile.R".
I am running RStudio. I want to use the Windows console (cmd.exe) to pipe "TestFile.R" directly into the "R Script" editor of RStudio, without launching a new thread of RStudio.
This command in the console does exactly what I want:

```
rstudio -f TestFile.R
```

The contents of "TestFile.R" go straight into the RScript editor of the existing thread of RStudio.

It assumes, however, that "TestFile.R" is in the "bin" folder of RStudio, and also that
cmd.exe is running within that folder.
But I want to be able to do this from anywhere on my computer, using a console command like:

```
 pathToRstudio\rstudio -f pathToTestFile\TestFile.R
```

To give an example, on my computer, this command fails:

```
C:\"Statistical packages"\RStudio\bin\rstudio -f E:\"my project"\TestFile.R
```

By trial and error, I discovered these solutions:

1/ omit the "C:\" part

2/ avoid quotation marks in the pathToTestFile.

So this console command works fine:

```
"Statistical packages"\RStudio\bin\rstudio -f E:\myproject\TestFile.R
```

Of course, I still am very restricted ; my default folder has to be "C:\", and I cannot have spaces in the path to TestFile.R, even though spaces within the Rstudio path are apparently OK !?

Could somebody please explain to me how to write this command in a way that is completely generic with regard to path specification?
I want to be able to run it from any folder, and have TestFile.R in any other folder. I do not want hassles about folder names containing spaces.